# Using boolean masks in Pandas

Tags: python, boolean, pandas, mask

This is probably a trivial query but I can't work it out.

Essentially, I want to be able to filter out noisy tweets from a dataframe below

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 140381 entries, 0 to 140380
Data columns:
text          140381  non-null values
created_at    140381  non-null values
id            140381  non-null values
from_user     140381  non-null values
geo           5493  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), object(4)
```

I can create a dataframe based on unwanted keywords thus:

```
junk = df[df.text.str.contains("Swans")]
```

But what's the best way to use this to see what's left?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df[~df.text.str.contains("Swans")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following two options:

#### option 1:

```
df[-df.text.str.contains("Swans")]
```

#### option 2:

```
import numpy as np 
df[np.invert(df.text.str.contains("Swans"))]
```